# Need Vif value and not gvif

Tags: r, linear-regression

How do I get the VIF value without `Gvif` and `GVIF^(1/(2*Df))`. I have tried the command `vif(model)` and need just the vif value but I get the output as gvif

Comment: Can you post what the error was and the code you've written that result in such an error. As it stands the question didn't show any indication of things you've tried and it's hard to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the VIF value from a regression model, the simplest solution is using the `car` package:

```
library(car)
vif(model)
```

Which returns the `vif` value:

```
             gdp labour_participation           m_per1000f 
        1.100277             1.457567             1.667722 
     time_prison 
        1.247356
```

If you want to calculate the `VIF` value manually (the harder way to doing it but without using any library), you can do so to verify that the results you got from the above is indeed correct:

```
vif_lp <- 1/(1-(summary(lm(labour_participation ~ gdp + m_per1000f + time_prison, crime))$r.squared))
vif_lp
# returns [1] 1.457567
```